# Run 2 Nodejs app with PM2 on Azure Linux App Service

Tags: node.js, pm2, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I'm attempting to run two NodeJS applications on a single Linux Azure App Service. I start the PM2 with the ecosystem configuration shown below.

App1's domain name is app1.example.com.

App2's domain name is app2.example.com.

I see that APP1 is working properly, but APP2 is not. When I swap the configuration (APP2, APP1 in ecosystem.config.js), APP2 works but not APP1. As a result, I can only run one app.

When I attempt to debug APP2, I discover that the request app2.example.com is not reaching the application.

What is wrong with this approach, and can you recommend a better solution?

```
ecosystem.config.js
      module.exports = {
        apps: [
            {
                script: './app1/index.js',
                name: 'app1',
                watch: true,
                instances: '1', // To set 0/max for spread the app across all CPUs
                env: {
                    "NODE_ENV": "production",
                },
            },
            {
                script: './app2/index.js',
                name: 'app2',
                watch: true,
                instances: '1', // To set 0/max for spread the app across all CPUs
                env: {
                    "NODE_ENV": "production",
                },
            }
        ]
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the below steps to run the NodeJS applications with PM2 in a single Azure App service.

Create a new Folder and within it create two separate `Node JS` Applications.

Follow this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?tabs=windows&pivots=development-environment-vscode) to create Node JS Application.

[image]

Make sure both the Applications have `package.json` files.

- Open the Applications in `VSCode`.
- In each application folder install the PM2 with the below command separately in each application root folder.
  For App1 in myExpressApp1 root folder terminal.
  For App 2 in myExpressApp2 root folder terminal.

***OR***

You can run the PM2 globally on the applications root directory.

```cs
npm install pm2 -g
```

Start both the Applications using  `PM2` as mentioned in the [`azureossd`](https://azureossd.github.io/2022/02/22/Using-PM2-on-App-Service-Linux/).

```cs
pm2 start app.js --name="app1" --no-daemon
pm2 start app.js --name="app2" --no-daemon
```

[image]

- In Azure Portal, Create a Linux App Service with run time stack `Node`.
- From `Deployment Center`, deploy the code using `FTP` or `Git`.

[image]

As you are using `ecosystem configuration` add pm2 start `ecosystem.config.js` in the startup command.

Make sure your `ecosystem.config.js` is deployed in the Application root directory.

> I start the PM2 with the ecosystem configuration shown below.
> App1's domain name is app1.example.com.
> App2's domain name is app2.example.com.

If you have not configured the custom domains then, access your app's using the below URL`s.

```cs
https://YourWebApp.azurewebsites.net/app1
https://YourWebApp.azurewebsites.net/app2
```

AFAIK, the problem can be with configuration of the custom domains.
Make sure you have custom domains configured correctly.

In `ecosystem.config.js`, add the PORT No. below the `NODE_ENV`.

```js
env: { 
    "NODE_ENV": "production", 
    "PORT": 5000  
    },
env: { 
    "NODE_ENV": "production", 
    "PORT": 3000    
    },
```

Comment: For App2 Endup getting error saying port already in use. (any thoughts)
05:45:03 1|app2    | Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8080
----
05:45:03 1|app2    |   code: 'EADDRINUSE',
05:45:03 1|app2    |   errno: -98,
05:45:03 1|app2    |   syscall: 'listen',
05:45:03 1|app2    |   address: '::',
05:45:03 1|app2    |   port: 8080
05:45:03 1|app2    | }

Comment: Try to add different PORT No. and check once.

Comment: Came to know by default Azure App Service allows only 80 and 443 ports: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=platform-linux#configure-port-number